# Custom background for the index page only?

Tags: frontpage, custom-background

I am stuck at `add_custom_background`.

I can change background color/image but I only want to change my index page. Currently, the changes apply on the whole page.

I want to make the changes from WP-admin.

How can I specify it to a specific page ?

Edit:

I just checked im running 3.3.1. So my version is not supported to use  add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );

instead I want to use add_custom_background.

```
  if ( is_front_page() )
{
   add_custom_background();
}
```

Cant get it to work.

Comment: That is what it's supposed to do. For what you want, you'll have to "hack" the theme to do that and then add custom options in the admin.

Comment: So what do you suggest that i do in this case ?
Is there any other plugin i could use ?

Comment: As I said - "hack" the theme. I almost never trust plugins, so I would write it myself, but yeah, there could be a plugin for that :P

Comment: any suggestion ? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check in your callback function if you are an the front page.

Sample code for the theme’s `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_67480_theme_setup' );

function wpse_67480_theme_setup()
{
    $bg_options = array (
        'wp-head-callback' => 'wpse_67480_background_frontend',
        'default-color'    => 'f0f0f0',
        'default-image'    => '',
    );
    add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $bg_options );

    add_theme_support(
        'custom-header',
        array (
            'width'       => 960,
            'height'      => 200,
            'flex-height' => TRUE,
            'flex-width'  => TRUE,
            'header-text' => FALSE,
            'wp-head-callback' => 'wpse_67480_header_frontend',
        )
    );
}

wpse_67480_background_frontend()
{
    if ( is_front_page() )
    {
        _custom_background_cb();
    }
}

wpse_67480_header_frontend()
{
    if ( ! is_front_page() )
    {
        return;
    }

    // create your header code here
}
```

Comment: Im using wordpress 3.2 i think and that code sample you pasted is supported by 3.4.0 and above (  add_theme_support( 'custom-background'). I have to use add_custom_background since im not on that update. Thanks for the fast reply btw.

Comment: Please run the update. 3.2 has some unfixed security issues. The solution – check for `is_front_page()` in the callback – is the same there, just the registration is different.

Comment: I just checked im running 3.3.1. The only reason i havent updated yet is because i have over 30+ wp sites ( mobile sites ) and im really doubtful if it would ruin something or ruin any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the body class and define your background in your style.css

Example: 
background for frontpage:

```
body.home { background: #eee; } 

background for pages

body.page { background: #ccc; }

background for archive pages

body.archive { background ... }
```

and so on.
Just check your source code for the body class of the site you want to address.

If your background is for another element but body you can add the body class in front of it:

```
body.home .wrapper { background ... }
```

Comment: Thank for the answer , but what i wanna do is to make the admin of the site change his index page from wp-admin