# Custom background front page only ? is_front_page() issue?

Tags: themes, custom-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom background for the index page only?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67480/custom-background-for-the-index-page-only)

I need to get this right.

What iam looking for is to change background image from wp-admin , for front page only.

I get it work with add_custom_background(); in my functions.php. But that changes goes for the whole page.

I ve been told that i should use, if_front_page but i dont get it to work.

This is how far ive made it:

```
  if ( is_front_page() )
{
   add_custom_background();
}
```

Comment: Do not ask the same question again. Improve and extend the other question instead.

Comment: Sorry im new here , what do you mean by extend ?

Comment: Edit the other question you asked, add debug data and explain what didn’t work.

Comment: I edited the other one , but i have to wait until i can delete this one. thank you

Comment: Just ignore it, this question will be deleted automatically, or I will do it.